# Changing values on x and y axis on a histogram

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, histogram

I want to plot a histogram, how many scrabble words with 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 or 7 chars are found in a dictionary over x trials with a random hand.

The histogram should have the following values on the x and y axis: [image: MS Paint example]

I have a list with the results: `[0.33, 0.42, 0.33, 1.09, 0.3, 0.0]`, the first value means I've got an average of 0.33 of a 2 char word per hand over 100 trials. The second value is for a 3 chars word an so on.

At the moment I have something like this: [image: image saved from python]

On the x axis there is the avg amount of words, the y axis contains the amount of values (two values are the same, that's why the third line is being printed with value of 2). I have no idea how the code should look like.

Comment: If you have solved your problem please post the solution in an answer instead of editing your question.

Answer (score 2):

Solved with `pylab.bar()`:

```
pylab.figure()
pylab.bar(xaxis, plot_list, align='center', color='green')
pylab.title('Amount of scrabble words, possible to phrase from a random hand (100 trials)')
pylab.xlabel('Length of words')
pylab.ylabel('Average amount of words')
pylab.show()
```

Here is what the solution looks like: [image]